# Inserting R dataframe column to dataframe based on presence absence values

Tags: r

My input file is:

```
input_file <- structure(list(species = structure(1:3, .Label = c("x", "y", 
                                                                 "z"), class = "factor"), header1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), header2 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                               1L, 1L), header3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      -3L))
```

Here 1 and 0 indicate presence and absence.

Now, I need to convert this file (based on presence - absence values) to:

```
output_file <- structure(list(header1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                            "y"), class = "factor"), header2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                                                                                                   "y", "z"), class = "factor"), header3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("x", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "y", "z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -3L))
```

For this, first I try to melt my input file using reshape2:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(input_file, id.var = "species")
```

Now I am not sure how to create a dataframe to get my desired output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `reshape2` you could do:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(subset(df1,value>0),ave(value,variable,FUN = seq_along)~variable,value.var = "species")[-1]
  header1 header2 header3
1       y       y       x
2    <NA>       z       y
3    <NA>    <NA>       z
```

You can then replace the `NA` with the empty string

In base R, you could do:

```
df1 <- subset(reshape(input_file,-1,sep="",dir="long",idvar = "species"),header>0)
reshape(transform(df1,header = ave(time,time,FUN = seq_along)),dir="wide",idvar = "header",sep="")[-1]
    species1 species2 species3
y.1        y        y        x
z.2     <NA>        z        y
z.3     <NA>     <NA>        z
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution. It first does an `ifelse` on each row. If it finds a 1 it replaces it with the species name. If it finds a zero it writes a blank. The species column is then removed. The second line just ensures that any empty cells are moved to the bottom of the columns.

```
m <- t(apply(input_file, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == "1", x[1], ""))[-1,])
df <- as.data.frame(apply(m, 2, function(x) x[order(-nchar(x))]))
```

So we can see this matches your output file:

```
df
#>   header1 header2 header3
#> 1       y       y       x
#> 2               z       y
#> 3                       z

identical(df, output_file)
#> [1] TRUE
```